# What is the workaround if group_concat doesn't return a value

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement, group-concat

I have written a query which transforms a couple of rows based on a condition into columns.

However, there are cases where no row meets the condition but I want to return some results.

Below is a sample of the table and the results I am looking for.

Source table:

| id | respondent_id | demographic | question | answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | checked | Age | 30 |
| 2 | 1 | null | education | masters |
| 3 | 1 | checked | height | 1.8m |
| 4 | 1 | null | income | $1 |
| 5 | 1 | null | address | ISS |
| 6 | 1 | null | talent | dancing |
| 7 | 2 | checked | Age | 20 |
| 8 | 2 | null | education | high school |
| 9 | 2 | checked | height | 4m |
| 10 | 2 | null | income | $3.2 |
| 11 | 2 | null | address | High sea |
| 12 | 2 | null | talent | singing |

Sample results after transformation:

| id | respondent_id | Age | height | question | answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 30 | 1.8m | education | masters |
| 4 | 1 | 30 | 1.8m | income | $1 |
| 5 | 1 | 30 | 1.8m | address | ISS |
| 6 | 1 | 30 | 1.8m | talent | dancing |
| 8 | 2 | 20 | 4m | education | high school |
| 10 | 2 | 20 | 4m | income | $3.2 |
| 11 | 2 | 20 | 4m | address | High sea |
| 12 | 2 | 20 | 4m | talent | singing |

Current MySQL statement:

```
SET @sql = NULL;


SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      '(SELECT l.answer FROM source_table l where l.respondent_id = a.respondent_id AND  l.question = ', b.question,')
      AS ',b.question
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM source_table b
WHERE b.demographic IS NOT NULL;


SET @sql = 
CONCAT('SELECT respondents_id,    
              ',@sql,',
        a.question , a.answer     
        FROM   source_table a
        WHERE a.demographic IS NULL
        GROUP BY id
       ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

To clarify, the above query works when there are rows that are "checked" for the demographic column, however when there are no "checked" cells, the whole query fails.

So I would like a query that works under all conditions, whether there are demographic rows or not.

If there are no demographic rows, the query is supposed to return the data without the new columns

Comment: I'm a bit lost.  Can you explain why you are using dynamic SQL for this?

Comment: Thanks @ysth,
Your comment on the separator is very useful. I would make the changes

Comment: @Gordon Linoff it's a pivot table

Comment: @MikeT. changed my comment to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@FaNo_FN @ysth

I managed to fix it using the fiddle you had posted and your comments.

I added the following code between the 2 queries to check if the variable is set.

`SET @sql := IF(@sql IS NULL,'',@sql);`

I also added a second `CONCAT()` before the `GROUP_CONCAT` to add a ',' separator.

This is the link to the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&sample=sakila&fiddle=fe3a6148fb665af83c7c2f513c046dfc)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused on why you are using dynamic SQL.  Window functions seems to do what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when question = 'Age' then answer end) over (partition by respondent_id ) as age,
             max(case when question = 'height' then answer end) over (partition by respondent_id ) as height
      from source_table st
     ) t
where demographic is null;
```

I suppose you could use this as a template if you don't know the "checked" columns.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff,
I am using a dynamic query because, I won't know in advance the rows that contains the demographic variables.
This project is for a SAAS survey app

Answer (score 1):

I think your goal is to generate a query like this:

```
SELECT respondent_id, a.question , a.answer,
       (SELECT l.answer 
          FROM source_table l 
         WHERE l.respondent_id = a.respondent_id AND l.question = "Age") AS Age,
       (SELECT l.answer 
          FROM source_table l 
         WHERE l.respondent_id = a.respondent_id AND l.question = "height") AS height
    FROM   source_table a
    WHERE a.demographic IS NULL
 GROUP BY respondent_id, a.question , a.answer;
```

However, your current syntax is generating a query like this:

```
SELECT respondents_id,    
       SELECT l.answer FROM source_table l where l.respondent_id = a.respondent_id 
          AND  l.question = Age AS Age,
       SELECT l.answer FROM source_table l where l.respondent_id = a.respondent_id  
          AND  l.question = height AS height,
        a.question , a.answer     
        FROM   source_table a
        WHERE a.demographic IS NULL
        GROUP BY id;
```

There are no parentheses `()` wrapped around the `SELECT ..` correlated subqueries which will return the following error

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT l.answer FROM source_table l where l.respondent_id = a.respondent_id AND ' at line 2

You need to modify your syntax as following:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      '(SELECT l.answer 
          FROM source_table l where l.respondent_id = a.respondent_id 
          AND l.question = "', b.question,'") AS ',b.question)
  ) INTO @sql
FROM source_table b
WHERE b.demographic IS NOT NULL;

SELECT @sql; /*added in between to check the current variable value. Removable.*/

SET @sql = 
CONCAT('SELECT respondent_id, a.question , a.answer,
               ',@sql,'
        FROM   source_table a
        WHERE a.demographic IS NULL
        GROUP BY respondent_id, a.question , a.answer 
       ');
       
SELECT @sql; /*added in between to check the current variable value. Removable.*/

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2221d3e8a7119ac3015dba0018319e65)

Comment: Thanks @fano_fn,
The original query I am using actually has the parenthesis, I just forgot to add it while typing the question.

The issue I am facing is that the query doesn't work in all scenarios

Comment: I assume you're talking about the `demographic` column. What you're saying if all of the cells in that column are `NULL`, the query won't work?

Comment: exactly that!
it doesn't work when all the cells of that column are ```NULL```

Answer (score 1):

I would make your `GROUP_CONCAT` have `SEPARATOR ''` and start your first `CONCAT(` args with a `','`, and remove the comma after `SELECT respondents_id`. But some of your other syntax doesn't look right from just visual inspection.